# How to put songs on iPod without using iTunes/Apple Music from MacOS?

Tags: macos, music, ipod

I recently purchased an old **iPod Shuffle (4th Generation)** with **2 GB** internal storage.

I have some songs on an external drive that I want to transfer to iPod. But I'm not sure where to start.

Also, I don't see any option to transfer files from any other location apart from **Music** directory.

Also, keeping the song in the **Music** directory is not detected.

For example: I have kept a song as shown in the image:

[image]

Now, I was expecting it to be detected by iPod but unfortunately it was not detecting.

[image]

Any recommendations or easier ways on how to transfer songs without iTunes/Apple Music app?

Comment: Apple Music is built into macOS now unlike iTunes.  Is there a problem with using Apple Music?

Comment: Generally speaking Apple makes it difficult to **not** do it the recommended way as an effect of (presumably) making it simple/user friendly. And the recommended way with iOS devices and iPods is using music.app or for older versions of the OS iTunes. Like @Allan said is there a reason you can't use the recommended way?

Comment: @Allan How to do it with Apple Music? I'm not sure about it. Can you write an answer for that?

Comment: Have you tried searching for that info?  Try this: https://support.apple.com/en-us/118288

Comment: @Allan I was finally able to do it with Apple Music for external drive songs. I will add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do it without **iTunes/Apple** Music. The third party apps are charging too much to do this.

So, I did a hacky way to do it.

To add songs to **iPod** which are on the **external drives** or any other directory on the **local drives**.

**Steps:**

First, play a your song via **Apple Music/iTunes** from the location you have that song. Now, **Apple Music/iTunes** will create a directory `/Music/Media/<artist>/<album>` under **Music** directory and copies the song file into that directory automatically on your local.

Example:

[image]

Now, Go the iPod location, select Music tab and it will show the name of the artist.

Note: If you add newer songs belonging to the same artist, then it will go into the same directory by album.

Example:

[image]

Now, either you can do a sync of the entire music library or sync by artist/albums/genre/playlist selectively.

Click on **Apply** button to complete syncing.

You are done. That's how you do it.